# Removing Object from ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm seriously struggling with the ArrayList's remove method. I tried both the index and Object method in order to delete my object from the list. The object in the ArrayList and the object itself are the same, as their stack adresses are same. The following code:

```
System.out.println("ObjectinList i: " + arraylist.get(i));
System.out.println("ObjectToDelete 0: " + someClass.getsomeArray().get(0));
somearraylist.remove(someclass.getsomeArray().get(0));
System.out.println("VL i: " + arraylist.get(i));
```

Gives the following output:

```
ObjectinList i: someClass@599c4975
ObjectToDelete 0: someClass@599c4975
ObjectinList i: someClass@68e60073
```

Obviously the object at position i gets overwritten with another object when removing?!

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: are you using `toString() `?

Comment: I think you overlooked the `"Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices)."` bit in the documentation for `remove()`.

Comment: why are you using two different array lists in this example?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `toString()` to the objects you are storing, this will make debugging significantly easier.
2. Nothing is overwritten. This is a "virtual" array. When you remove the element at index 0, every element to the right of it (1, 2, ...) shifts one to the left.  former index 1 is now index 0, former index 2 is now index 1, *etc.*

Comment: Thanks alot, got my problem now. I was confused that there was actually another object to be found in the arraylist, yet I didn't realize that I added it accidentially at a prior point in code.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList removes objects based on the equals(Object obj) method. So you should implement properly this method. Something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof ArrayTest)) return false;
    ArrayTest o = (ArrayTest) obj;
    return o.i == this.i;
}
```

in your object class

Answer (score 0):

to quote [`remove`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) (bolding added for emphasis):

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). **Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices)**. Returns the element that was removed from the list.

I.e., the second call to `get(i`) returns the element that was in position `i+1` before removing element `i`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anyone problem : it works!
When you remove a node from a list (an Object from ArrayList), at the same position in the list there will be another Object, the next of the one you removed! When you remove some from a List(ArrayList or LinkedList) the list will be compacted!